# How to use array in autocomplete textbox jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, textbox

For Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() { 
        var availableTags = [ "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"];
        var availableTagsCode = ["1", "2", "3"]; 
        $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    });
</script>

<input id="tags" name="name">
<input id="tags_code" name="code">
```

Actually, I have tried to change code while select suggestion using following code:

```
$("#tags_code").val(availableTagsCode);
```

I need to select suggestion test if i will select `0`th array from tag the `0`th code should assign to `name="code"` textbox.
Please help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `select` event handler:

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var index = availableTags.indexOf(ui.item.value);
        $("#tags_code").val(availableTagsCode[index]);  
    }
});
```

Here is the [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwdav69t/1/).

Actually, jQuery UI allows you to use an array of objects with `value` and `label` properties when you provide `source`.
So, something like this will work and look better:

```
var tags = [
    {"label": "ActionScript", "value": 1},
    {"label": "AppleScript", "value": 2},
    {"label": "Asp", "value": 3}
];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: tags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tags_code").val(ui.item.value);  
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo for the second approach](http://jsfiddle.net/mwdav69t/2/).

If you don't want the value to be replaced after choosing, you can use custom property instead of `value`:

```
var tags = [
    {"label": "ActionScript", "code": 1},
    {"label": "AppleScript", "code": 2},
    {"label": "Asp", "code": 3}
];

$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ 
    source: tags,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#tags_code").val(ui.item.code);  
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mwdav69t/3/).

Comment: Thank you @Kurmangaliyev. Actually i need lable name in in '#tags'. But both are changing to value only .

Answer (score 4):

Set **[`select`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)** event handler

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp"];
  var availableTagsCode = ["1", "2", "3"];
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(e, ui) {
      $('#tags_code').val(availableTagsCode[availableTags.indexOf(ui.item.value)]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="tags" name="name">
<input id="tags_code" name="code">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#textBoxID").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, responce) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "webservice_Name.asmx/webservice_functionName",
                    method: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ parameterName: request.term }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        responce(data.d);
                        if (data.d.length > 0)
                            $('#spnError').text("");
                        else
                            $('#spnError').text("Not Matching Any Result");
                        console.log(data.d.length);
                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, ui) {
                console.log("You selected: " + ui.item.label);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "webservice_Name.asmx/webservice_functionNameForgetID",
                    method: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ parameterName: ui.item.label }),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);

                    },
                    error: function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```