# autocomplete textbox didn't works

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I want to code an autocomplete textbox using codeigniter. I have tried multiple ways to solve this, but there is no result display. Below are the code:

in my model (named Kepakaran_m.php) :

```
 function search($bidang){
    $this->db->like('bidang',$bidang, 'both');
    return $this->db->get('kexpt103kodbidang')->result();
 }
```

in my controller (named: Expert.php):

```
  function search($bidang){
  $result = $this->Kepakaran_m->search($bidang);
    if (count($result) > 0){
        foreach ($result as $res)
            $results[] = $res->bidang;
        echo json_encode($results);
     }
  }
```

in my view (named : kepakaran.php):

```
 <script type="">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#bidang").autocomplete({
            source:'<?php echo base_url('expert/search') ?>',  
        });
    });
  </script> 

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form" novalidate>           
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Bidang Kepakaran</label>
            <div class="input-group col-md-6">
               <textarea name="bidang" cols="1" rows="1" wrap="soft" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" id="bidang" type="text" autocomplete="off" ></textarea>

            </div>
        </div>
      </div></form>
```

any idea on how to solve this? Thank you

Comment: shouldn;t this expert/search be Expert/search

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429866/how-to-use-array-in-autocomplete-textbox-jquery

Comment: i believe autocomplete takes key value pair

Comment: thanks @Satya :) but from my understanding. the controller name is not a case sensitive when in view/model. it is sensitive when code in controller itself.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam i've go through this before for an answer, but it doesn't help me so much. thanks ya :)

Comment: @AgamBanga thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#bidang").autocomplete({

        source: "<?php echo base_urlecho base_url('expert/search'); ?>",
        minLength: 1,
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.column1);
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.column1);
            return false;
        },
        response: function(event, ui) {
            if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                $(this).val('');
            }
        }
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li>")
            .append("<a>" + item.column1 + "</a>")
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
</script>
```

// controller

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $data = $query->result();
    echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: i've tried this and it doesn't works and bring some error in my code. btw, thanks ya :)